# No styles are added when rendering the page

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a problem with styles when rendering a page.
There are no problems connecting styles on any other page
This is pug with product.pug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <title>#{product.product_name}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        include layout/menu.pug
        include layout/myProfile.pug
    </header>
    <main>
        | there will be data about the product
    </main>
    include layout/footer.pug
</body>
</html>
```

This is code with app.js:

```
app.get('/product/:productId', (req, res) => {
    if (req.params["productId"] !== undefined &&
        req.params["productId"] > 0) {
        conn.query(`SELECT * 
                    FROM product
                    WHERE product_id = ${req.params["productId"]}`, (err, product) => {
            if(err) {throw err;}
            if(product.length > 0) {
                res.render('product', {
                    userName: req.session.userName,
                    successAuthentication: req.session.successAuthentication,
                    isWorker: req.session.isWorker,
                    product
                })
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(404);
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(404);
    }
});
```

Styles are stored in the public folder, and app is used to use styles

```
app.use(express.static (path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Any other page doesn't have a problem with styles.
I can't solve this problem, so I will be grateful for any hint

Comment: I suggest removing parts of the logic/page bit by bit until you find the bare minimum of code required to cause this problem. Then the solution will likely be a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your express static folder like this code below:

```js
app.use(expresss.static('public'));
```

Now, you can try to create your `public` folder in your app root and move your `styles` folder into your `public` folder and its Will working fine.

I hope it can help you.